# Mule | Data weave | Merge / Concat two objects in json

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm working on one scenario where I'm expecting the below output by giving the input.

Input:

```
[{
"Name": "", 
"Age": 30,
"Color": "", 
"Height": ""    
},
{
"Name": "", 
"Age": "",
"Color": "", 
"Height": 5.6
}
]
```

Output:

```
{Name: "", 
Age: 30,
Color: "", 
Height: 5.6
}
```

Comment: The ask is very open-ended. Can you narrow it down to what variations to input exist and on the basis of what logic/rules do you derive the output, given the input that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your case, but it may not work with more complex structures:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((item, acc={}) -> item mapObject (($$): $ ++ (acc[$$] default "")))
```

This script assumes all elements have the same fields.